# Candump - candumpanalyzer : command not found

Tags: linux, npm, npm-install, can-bus, canutils

Operating System: Rasbian

I am trying to follow this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@canboat/canboatjsto to use the following command : `candump can0 | candumpanalyzer.`
However, after trying all these commands:

```
$ sudo npm install @canboat/canboatjs
$ sudo npm install --force @canboat/canboatjs
$ sudo npm i @canboat/canboatjs
$ sudo installing can-utils
```

It still tells me that candumpanalyzer: command not found.

I get Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@canboat/canboatjs/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build' and I am in sudo ...

Could it be a problem with Raspbian ?

I am running out of ideas to try and use this command. Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `npx candump can0 | candumpanalyzer` or install your package globally using `sudo npm install -g @canboat/canboatjs`

Comment: Thanks @isAif but when I install globally, I get Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@canboat/canboatjs/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build' and I am in sudo ...

Comment: Try without *sudo*, also try the *npx* command.

Comment: I tried but still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your *node_modules* directory and run the following command:

`find -name "candump*"`

You will get the following result:

```
./node_modules/.bin/candumpanalyzerjs
./node_modules/@canboat/canboatjs/bin/candumpanalyzerjs
```

This means there is no `candumpanalyzer` but `candumpanalyzerjs`.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/canboat/canboatjs#candumpanalyzer) they have provided the following code as example:

> This program takes input in the candump format and outputs canboat json format
>
> Example: `candump can0 | candumpanalyzer`

But even in their repository if you search for `candumpanalyzer` you will only get result in `readme.md` file.

Comment: I submitted PR to fix this typo and it's fixed now.